# regular expression matching - how to restrict the number of times which a discontinuous pattern appears

Tags: regex

I try to use regular expression to express the full permutation of the string "abc", which includes "abc","acb","bac","bca","cab","cba". I know `(a|b|c){3}` can match a three-characters string that only contains "a", "b" and "c". But how to add an additional condition to specify that "a", "b" and "c" each appears only one time?

Comment: `([abc])((?!\1)[abc])(?!\2|\1)[abc]` https://regex101.com/r/rT7yL3/1

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks. It works. But what if I want the regex of the full permutation of the string "abcdefgh"? I have to use `?!` many times. Is there any other simple ways?

Comment: For **matching**, and for the case of **set** of character (the characters are unique), I can only think of this solution if I were to write it in regex. You need as many negative look-ahead as the number of characters in the set, and the alternation in the negative look-ahead need to exclude the character matched by all previous capturing groups.

Comment: @nhahtdh Actually I try to make a regex to match a set of string, like `str1 str2 str3 ...`. `strm` and `strn` can be the same. If you find a new method to solve this problem, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex isn't really a tool made for this, and if it's really just this combination, you might want to use a "simpler" soltion not relying on regex.

This is how I would implement that in Java

```
Set<Character> allowedChars = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("abc".toCharArray()));
for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
    if (allowedChars.contains(c)) {
        allowedChars.remove(c);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
return true; // all chars in the string were in the allowed chars once
```

This of course right now only works for unique character combinations. If you want some chars to appear multiple times, you should switch from a `Set` to a `List` (which allows duplicate values)

It should be rather simple to get this into another language of your choice.

Comment: I have to solve this problem in a bash script which does not have strong power in coding. Anyway, thanks.